# InertiaJS loses remember when I'm back on the page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm using Inertia JS in Vue with the Options API.

I have a single property that needs remembering, so when I set it in a method I'm going:

```
Inertia.remember(booth, 'active')
```

Then on a `created` or `mounted` hook I'm restoring it like this:

```
this.active = Inertia.restore('active') ?? 4;
```

This works *ONCE* when refreshing the page. On second refresh it loses the remember and goes to the default 4. I guess I have to remember it in the `mounted` hook as well?

However, when I navigate to a different page (that has nothing to do with this component) and then use an Inertia link to go back to the first page the state is always lost and `restore()` returns `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like this, should work

```
beforeUnmount() {
 Inertia.remember(booth, 'active')

},
mounted() {
 this.active = Inertia.restore('active') ?? 4;

 },
```

Comment: Same result - when I leave the component it actually sees booth (checked with logging), but then when I navigate back to this component it resorts to 4 since it sees restore('active') as null